# Laravel 5.8 : Dynamically change throttle allowance not working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, throttling, laravel-5.8

I'm building an API with dynamic throttling. I've setup my middleware as `throttle:rate_limit,1` and therefore set a mutator on my User model:

```
public function getRateLimitAttribute()
{
    if($this->subscribed()) {
        return $this->subscription()->plan->rpm;
    }
    return 2;
}
```

However, this seems not to work at all. I was thinking maybe I'm throttling twice, so I removed throttle middleware from `app/Http/Kernel.php` `api` group but no luck. Other idea was maybe mutator is not being fired, but checking by `$user->rate_limit` shows proper value (10). Even after explicitly defining `public $rate_limit = 10` in my model and commenting out the mutator - no success. The `X-RateLimit-Remaining` header shows `-1` and `X-RateLimit-Limit` is equal to `0`.

Guys, do you have any ideas what's happening here? I'm using Dingo API if that's any help.